# Data not rendered in Vue Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have tried to render data to the home page but nothing displayed despite there being no error. Here is my code

**app.js**

```js
import Home from './components/Home';
const routes = [{ name: 'home',path: '/home',component: Home},];
const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});
const app = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router },{data: {message:'Hello Vue!'}}, Home)).$mount('#app');
```

**Home.vue**

```js
<p>{{ message }}</p>
```

Comment: Please format your code so we can help you better :)

Comment: I have added that piece of code,nothing changed

Comment: as you are using laravel have  you print in blade file.?

Comment: yes,I am getting error "ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\0130share\resources\views\home.blade.php)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the parent data since your Home component is a child component.

Home vue

```
<div id="app">
<p>{{ this.$parent.message }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to render the HTML-Content you provide, you have to tell the starting point for vue. This is done like this

Your code

```
import Home from './components/Home';
const routes = [{ name: 'home',path: '/home',component: Home},];
const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});
const app = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router },{data: {message:'Hello Vue!'}}, Home)).$mount('#app');
```

inside blade file

```
<div id="app">
<p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```